# Downloading CopyNumber450k package from Bioconductor

Tags: bioconductor, illumina

I am trying to download CopyNumber450k package in the R processor on my laptop in order to see if I could do a step of protocol for my research proffessor.  I was unable to successfully download the package I think (because it was too outdated for the newest version of R?) The version of R I have downloaded is 3.4.1. This package appears to work on the version 1.8.0 of R. I thought this was strange, as that seems really old. I then tried to see if this download was possible using some sort of e-version of an R-processor : https://rdrr.io/bioc/CopyNumber450k/   Even the e-version appeared to be unable to find and download this package of R. I have a feeling that I may be misinterpreting something? I tried to find an equivalent package that could run on the newer version of R and didn’t seem to find anything. Then, I tried to see if it was possible to download an old version of R. I couldn’t find a clear way to do that either. Does anyone on bioinformatics stack exchange have insight regarging what I may be doing wrong, something i may be misinterpreting, or how I may overcome this challenge?
Thanks

Comment: This is more of a troubleshooting question than a bioinformatics question. It would be better to search for your specific error on Google, than post a question here. You can probably find something on StackOverflow, or an R-specific site

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to explain better what you have tried, including some code. You say that you were unsuccessful to download it, because of an outdated version of R. How did you do that?

I am not sure what you have tried, but if you read the instructions for installation [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.0/bioc/html/CopyNumber450k.html), you need to type the following in R console:

```
## try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") 
biocLite("CopyNumber450k")
```

Show us what kind of error you get from this. Then we can maybe help you further.